# Applications suspended when switching user?

Tags: ubuntu, x11, users, kde, multiuser

I've using 2 user and switch them between works using this command:

```
dm-tool switch-to-user workuser1
```

and using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> /<kbd>F8</kbd> to switch users after logged+ in.

But when I switch user, some applications doesn't run/downloads stopped (eg. KTorrent, Hakuneko-Desktop). I believe this did not happen in older version of Ubuntu (18.04), I'm using 20.04. Similar problem [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/382992)

What's the workaround so the application/downloads would still work even when user is switched?

**Already Tried 1**

VNC using the following but it shows blank screen and the downloads still stop when switching user.

```
/usr/bin/x11vnc -auth /var/run/lightdm/root/:0 -display WAIT:0 -forever -shared -rfbport 5900 -localhost -passwd foobar12
```

**Already Tried 2**

Running using display `:1` (user B's screen), but it doesn't work (nothings shown or error):

```
DISPLAY=:1.0 ktorrent &
```

**Already Tried 3**

```
QT_QPA_PLATFORM=offscreen ktorrent
```

The bad part: you cannot see the main windows, but the good part: download won't be suspended when switching user

Comment: If the problem is just off-screen rendering as mentioned in the link you provided, you can use text-based alternatives to overcome that.I don't know any text-based alternative for **Hakuneko** but you can use [Aria2](https://www.addictivetips.com/ubuntu-linux-tips/download-torrents-from-the-command-line-linux/) to download torrents without GUI.

Comment: @ParsaMousavi i use `gallery-dl` for downloading manga, but i still like ktorrent better than any other torrent clients, would it be work if i remote other user from other user?